# Making UIScrollView (and contents) opaque

Tags: iphone, uiscrollview

I'm trying to speed up my `UIScrollView` and one method I know of is to set everything to be opaque. I think I have done so, to my `UIScrollView`, its contentView, the contentView's tiledLayer (I have a `CATiledLayer` as the actual useful bit that the users see), and on the `UIView` that all of this sits in. But despite all of that when I look it through the Core Animation instrument with 'Color Blended Layers' turned on the scrollview's contents are shaded red showing they are transparent. The only green bits are outside the bounds of the contentview (which I can only see when it pans out to the side and then bounces back).

Is there something built in to ScrollViews, or `CATiledLayers` that could be ignoring 'setOpaque:' or have I messed up my view hierarchy and left something not-opaque?

Comment: Hi, have you ever managed to make UIScrollView's zooming view be really opaque? I am too heaving a difficulties to accomplish that, since it looks like everything is set right, but in Instruments it looks otherwise. Thanks.

Comment: Nope I never managed to fix it. I bought an iPhone 4S and that sped things up just fine :-)

Answer (score 0):

To answer the question "Have I messed up my view hierarchy and left something not-opaque?", from https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2239/_index.html:

> UIView implements a useful description method. In addition, it implements a recursiveDescription method that you can call to get a summary of an entire view hierarchy.

So, call `-recursiveDescription` on the topmost view, and check each subview for `opaque = NO;`.